# Copy local SQLite Database to iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

i am doing some experiments with coredata and objective-c.
My application works fine in the simulator.

It also works on my iPodTouch. **But how to i copy my local database to my device?**

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the sqlite file out of the simulator directory structure (under ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator) and put it into your project to be included in the Resources directory.  Once there you can either:

1. Copy the file during runtime to your documents directory to make it writeable; or
2. Reference it directly from within the app bundle to make it a read-only database

Depending on your application needs.

Comment: Sounds good. But how to reference it directly from within the app bundle to make it a read-only database?

Comment: I tried this. but it doenst work :-(

NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"bundle://Locations.sqlite"];
[persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error]

Comment: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Locations" ofType:@"sqlite"] will give you a string path back. Then turn that into a URL with [NSURL fileURLWithPath:] will return the url you then pass into Core Data.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution (Thanks Marcus S. Zarra)

Change this

```
NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Locations.sqlite"]]
```

into this:

```
NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Locations.sqlite"]];
```